# java HTTPConnection connect to ip

Tags: java, http, dns, ip, httpconnection

I want to handle data from a website. I need to handle sessions, so I need to send cookies. But if my program waits longer than 60 seconds to request a new site, the DNS resolver will bring me a new ip so my program will connect to another server which doesn't have my session.

Is it possibile to connect to the same server (IP) via HTTPConnection?

Comment: personally i'd use apache http components (http://hc.apache.org/) for anything non-trivial

Answer (score 1):

you could resolve the host name to an ip at the start, rewrite the url to use the IP instead of the host name and then you wont have to worry about DNS at all

Comment: This may not work if this is a shared hosting where the hostname is important.

Comment: @rekire that's what the Host-header is for. You always connect to an IP address. I do not know if the HttpConnection offers this option (say in a constructor parameter named `virtualHost` or by setting a property), or if it automatically uses the host portion of the URL you feed it.

Comment: ...which is why i'd use apache httpComponents

Comment: this doesn't work, i wrote a workaround with java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "300");